# Can you use Python as a data source in Tableau?

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am trying to use a Python Script as a Data Source in Tableau, as you can in Microsoft Power BI where any Pandas data frames are exposed as 'tables'. All I can find so far is using a .TDE or .Hyper extract API to produce an intermediate file but I would like the data to be more dynamic.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you by you would like the data to be more dynamic? You can write `.csv` from pandas and then import those files.

Comment: As @Jason says, run a python script on a schedule that outputs to a csv then connect tableau to the csv. To refresh in Tableau Desktop, just hit F5. If you need to optimize for size/speed/Server upload, then I would look to the Extract API but csv might be sufficient.